# How to append a list of data.frames to a data.frame for merge?

Tags: r, list, merge

I have a list of data.frames from an `lapply`, let's call it `dflist`. I would like to merge these files to an existing data.frame which is currently not in the list (call it `master`).

If I had a new list of data.frames where `master` is the first element, and the next elements are the elements from `dflist` I could issue `Reduce(merge, new_list)`. How can I arrive to this list?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)

master <- data.table(id = 1:5, var = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
setkey(master, "id")
dflist <- list(data.table(id = 1:5, z1 = runif(5)), data.table(id = 1:5, z2 = runif(5)))
lapply(dflist, function(x) {setkey(x, "id")})
```

---

`Reduce(merge, dflist)` works perfectly. I would like to include `master` into the list as the first element to merge each z variable in the data.tables to that file.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Do you mean by merge to add the data.frames to `master` row-wise, or do you mean to append unique columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe

```
Reduce(merge, dlist, init=master)
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution indeed works for the problem (although it does not answer the question itself).

Comment: You can append `master` to `dlist` as `dlist[[length(dlist)+1]] <- master`

Comment: Yes, you are right. With `init` it is no problem that `master` won't be the first element.

Comment: If you worried about master being the last element, you can merge `rev(dlist)`.