# joining a list of data.frames to a single data.frame

Tags: r, do.call

I'm not quite smart enough to understand lists, I guess... Say I have a dataframe `df` thusly:

```
> df <- data.frame(id=1, data=runif(3))
> df
  id      data
1  1 0.9343525
2  1 0.9950256
3  1 0.3557431
```

and I want to join a list of other data frames *after* it: `df2 <- lapply(2:3, function(x) data.frame(id=x, data=runif(3)))`

Easily enough, this works with `append()`, as pointed out on [stackexchange already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949277/how-to-append-a-list-of-data-frames-to-a-data-frame-for-merge). BUT: my first dataframe is now all muddled up... what am I doing wrong here?

```
> append(df2, df, after=0)
$id
[1] 1 1 1 1 1

$data
[1] 0.9343525 0.9950256 0.3557431 0.2047378 0.6395048

[[3]]
  id      data
1  2 0.5339489
2  2 0.8704095
3  2 0.7036925

[[4]]
  id      data
1  3 0.5548773
2  3 0.4692710
3  3 0.8388874
```

I can't `rbind()` the list into a single df because of this, and I'm pretty stumped. Pointers would be highly appreciated!

Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe just `df2[[3]] <- df`? Or a more robust approach `df2[[length(df2) + 1]] <- df`

Comment: @DavidArenburg but that would add `df` to the end of the list, OP wants `df` first. Maybe `do.call(rbind, append(list(df), df2))`?

Comment: Then just `c(list(df), df2)` I guess.

Comment: You're right, no need to use `append` as the OP tried and I followed.

Comment: `c(list(df), df2)` works, thanks @DavidArenburg!

So I need to pump the dataframe into a list() before joining? Good to know.

Comment: If you'll answer, I'll mark it as correct, but it seems I cannot mark comments here as valid answers.

Comment: Dataframes are a special types of lists in which each column is an element. When you `c()` then directly you're appending the columns to the list of data frames. Wrapping in `list()` makes it a list of a list.